# Convert PSD to SVG

Tags: svg, converters, photoshop

It is possible way that PSD file can convert into SVG file or using thirdparty software without sacrificing quality i found this [website](http://vectormagic.com/) but for image to vector.

I only need coverter or plugins for Photoshop or in Illustrator export as SVG

Comment: You can use the free editor at https://www.photopea.com/ to import a psd file and then export as an svg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to you use the free vesion of that website vectormagic just save your psd to image then process it to vectormagic website but remember almost 20% of quality is sacrifice because this is vector, to be sure for best result quality make an image with solid color or vetorized images without shadow blue or glow.

If you're knowledgeable in Illustrator here the plug in from [Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/inspire/2013/09/exporting-svg-illustrator.html) but then Illutrator is different in Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a 2-part question and requires a 2-part answer. Assuming you're going strictly from raster graphic to vector:

1. You have to get a good raster to vector conversion. Illustrator is good for this if you import your raster into AI and play around with tracing. You'll get decent results, but nothing beats doing the conversion by hand or starting from a vector to begin with. -- If you're starting with vectors already, you can just copy your shapes and paths to Adobe Illustrator (AI).
2. Once you have your vector is in AI, it's just a matter of using Save As : SVG. If you're using it for web, SVG 1.1 profile is the best option since it's the most compatible with browsers.

2B. If you're doing multiple vectors at once, place each vector into its own artboard inside AI. Once you've done that, you can fit each artboard to the artwork so that the canvas hugs your art. Save As SVG and choose the option "use artboards."  -- This will save all the vectors within that AI file as individual SVGs and will use the artboard names a file names.

NOTE: while you can use plug-ins and automated converters to do this, doing it manually will result in the best quality output.